# Out Of Memory issue in J2ME

Tags: java-me

I have developed a J2me(LWUIT) project.

It Contains more than 200 fields in a form and it takes memory internally around 10laks. When midlet starts, I haven't memory for further process. In My Application i have reused some form(Implemented inheritance, Child form extended Parent form).

How to tweak code for out of memory Exception to avoid. Kindly give me your suggestion to solve its issues.

Answer (score 0):

200 fields? Like TextFields or what? If so, I think that is too cumbersome for an ordinary java mobile device. It depends on what you are working on, i will suggest dynamic thread.... J2ME tutorial at http://www.tutorialmasterng.blogspot.com